Error 500 al usar mi carrito
Estoy tratando de llevar un proyecto a produccion por primera vez, usando Laravel y casi todo funciona bien , a excepcion de las rutas del carrito me arroja un error 500 mi pregunta es tengo que hacer otra cosa en el .htaccess o es otro problema?
Este es mi controlador de carrito
public function agregar(Request $request, $productoId)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $producto = Producto::findOrFail($productoId);

    // Busca o crea un carrito para el usuario
    $carrito = Carrito::firstOrCreate(['user_id' => $user->id]);

    // Busca el item en el carrito o crea uno nuevo
    $cartItem = $carrito->productos()->where('producto_id', $productoId)->first();

    if ($cartItem) {
        if ($cartItem->pivot->cantidad < $producto->cantidad) {
            $cartItem->pivot->increment('cantidad');
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('cliente')->with('error', 'No puedes añadir más de la cantidad disponible.');
        }
    } else {
        $carrito->productos()->attach($productoId, ['cantidad' => 1]);
    }

    return redirect()->route('cliente')->with('success', 'Producto añadido al carrito');
}

public function eliminar($id)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $carrito = Carrito::where('user_id', $user->id)->firstOrFail();
    $carrito->productos()->detach($id);

    return redirect()->route('carrito.mostrar')->with('success', 'Producto eliminado del carrito');
}


public function mostrar()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $carrito = Carrito::where('user_id', $user->id)->with('productos')->first();
    $total = 0;

    if ($carrito) {
        $total = $carrito->productos->sum(function ($item) {
            return $item->precio * $item->pivot->cantidad;
        });
    }

    return view('cliente.carrito', ['carrito' => $carrito, 'total' => $total]);
}

Y este es mi .htacces lei por ahi que debe manejarse de cierta maneras algunas redirecciones sera este el caso?
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>


Error aquí: $cartItem = $carrito->productos()->where('producto_id', $productoId)->first(); ponlo de este modo $cartItem = $carrito->productos()->where('producto_id', $productoId->first()); Si sigue dando error conviene que revises el log de errores y agregues a la pregunta el mensaje de error.

Es que como tal, ya me funciono en la parte local, mi error ya es en produccion jeje, como menciono es la primera vez que hago un deploy
